# How to link local HTML pages with strings in a navigation drawer?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-webview, navigation-drawer

I have a simple app with a webview to load local HTML pages, I put all my files inside assets, now in my navigation drawer I want to have some text/links that open these pages, I tried to follow some tuts on the web but somehow I can't make it happen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My code on android studio:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#ffffffff">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="History Of S.Johnson High School"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/sjohnson"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Side navigation drawer UI -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/navList"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:background="#ffeeeeee"/>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private WebView mWebView;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private String mActivityTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

    addDrawerItems();
    setupDrawer();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

private void addDrawerItems() {
    String[] osArray = { "Android", "iOS", "Windows", "OS X", "Linux" };
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Time for an upgrade!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private void setupDrawer() {
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {


        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Navigation!");
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }


        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**MyAppWebViewClient.java**

```
public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().length() == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

**themes.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="app_name">Info</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
<string name="drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to load yours html file from assets into WebView by clicking items in drawerMenu? If it's so you you need to add this lines to onClickListener of yours listView in drawer:

```
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Time for an upgrade!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //load file to webView
        mWebView.loadUrl("REPLACE_IT_WITH_PATH_TO_FILE");
        //close drawer
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is what I want exactly, Thank You very much for your assistance, one last think, if I want to put more items on my drawerMenu do I have to put all of them inside onClickListener like you do above?

Comment: @Paolo_Modeno in the body of onItemClick() method you receive an argument `position`. So you can create an array of file_paths and load file to webView from it in form `ARRAY_OF_PATHS_TO_FILE[position]`;

Comment: Thank you once again my friend, I understand now how it works. I appreciate your help man!

Comment: Sorry for the disturbance @mohax can you provide a simple example, I have no clue about Java or android. I tried various methods from google but nothing works on my code!

Comment: @Paolo_Modeno Example of what do you want?

Comment: I want to have some strings in the drawer menu and each string to open a different local html page, now everything I do it opens the same one. Sorry brother if you have no time there is no problem. @mohax

Comment: I can't help you in comments... And I also need to see yours code, so why not to post new question with yours problem? I'm sure, that there are a lot of people who can help you this way)

Comment: Ok my friend I will post a new one, sorry again for being annoying :) Thank you! @mohax